# Изменение цвета и размера шрифта

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте!
Вот как сделал фон:

```
<SELECT onChange="document.bgColor=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
  <OPTION VALUE="red"> красный
  <OPTION VALUE="2E8B57"> морской волны
  <OPTION VALUE="87CEEB"> голубой
  <OPTION VALUE="brown"> коричневый
  <OPTION VALUE="yellow"> желтый
  <OPTION VALUE="blue"> синий
  <OPTION VALUE="FFFFFF" SELECTED> белый
</SELECT>
```

Как бы мне теперь сделать чтобы цвет и размер текста на страничке так же менялся(Через Select)? На страничке использую каскадные стили CSS.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById(div_id).style.JS_property_reference = "new_CSS_property_value";
```

Comment: Например

Comment: Немного не понятно как это использовать?

Answer (score 1):

`document.body.style.color=this.value;` Только не надо забывать, что цвета в hex должны начинаться с #.

Comment: О как просто аказывается. Оргомное спасибо! Вот только как теперь с размером текста быть?